# Sublime Text 3. Не получается закомментировать код

Tags: html, sublime-text-3, emmet

В Sublime Text 3 не могу закомментировать код. Пробую CTRL + / не реагирует. EMMET установлен. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: а раньше получалось?

Comment: Нет.. Как установил такая проблема сразу была.. Но только сейчас понадобилось часто использовать..

Comment: эта комбинация должна быть по-умолчанию. Проверьте, есть ли у Вас в хоткеях по умолчанию такая строка `{ "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },`